# Module not found running on command line

Tags: python

I have the following project structure:

```
project/
    example/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        boo.py
        meh.py
    tests/
        example/
            test_foo.py
            test_boo.py
            test_meh.py
```

As example, I'm importing `foo.py` in `boo.py` as `import example.foo as f`. And I'm running tests with `python3 -m pytest -s -v --cov tests` on root folder (project). The unit tests are running very smooth but when I try to run a single file as `python3 example/boo.py` I got an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

Comment: What is the right approach?

Comment: The right approach is not to run modules directly.

Comment: Note that pytest will also not run the modules, since there is no `test` prepended. Perhaps if you pass the `--docttest-modules` option, but then it will run the doctests, not the actual modules.

Comment: Ok. Im new to python and this could sound strange, but each file from module should not be imported by relative files?

Comment: Why should they not be?

Comment: I'm splitting my code into several files to avoid a large single file and keep responsabilities separeted. I don't understand what do you mean by 'The right approach is not to run modules directly'. Could you explain, please?

Comment: A module should be imported, not run like a script. That is what a module is for. If, for some reason, you really really feel you need to execute module, then 1/ reconsider, 2/ rewrite your module, 3/ wrap a script around that module by calling the necessary function(s) inside the module (and keep the script itself relatively short).

Comment: Got that! So I should have a script and run the script, not the module. Right?

Comment: Yup. __________

Comment: Dumb question: is possible to have a script inside module folder and run it importing other files from module?

Comment: Put scripts in a separate directory next to your package, e.g. `project/example/` and `project/scripts/`.

Comment: It may be worth reading up on [Python packaging](https://packaging.python.org/), though admittedly, there is a lot to read and learn. It definitely extends outside the scope of your question, but it would hopefully answer questions such as about where scripts should go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modules inside a package shouldn't really be run (some exceptions).

But, you can set a PYTHONPATH before running the module if you really want. For a one off, use e.g.

```
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) python3 example/boo.py
```

---

An alternative is to use relative imports: `from . import foo as f` inside `boo.py`. But that still implies that modules shouldn't really be run.

---

To elaborate a bit more:
A module should be imported, not run like a script. That is what a module is for. If, for some reason, you really really feel you need to execute module, then 1/ reconsider, 2/ rewrite your module, 3/ wrap a script around that module by calling the necessary function(s) inside the module (and keep the script itself relatively short).

Note that `setuptools` already has this functionality through [entry points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html).

A simpler alternative is to use a proper

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

line at the end of your module, where `main()` calls into your module functionality, then execute the module using the Python `-m` switch:

```
python -m mypackage.mymodule
```

But, again, try and limit this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

It's usually a problem with environment variables. You can force the path using the following, and the import should work under all circumstances:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/absolute/module/path")
import local_module
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error, first try to import the same module in interactive shell of python with
`python`

```py
import module
```

if this imports successfully, try checking the paths using `sys` in the interactive shell

```
print(sys.path)
```

This will print a list of paths which are considered, Now do the same in your python file add the below lines above all imports.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

this will also print a list of paths. Now compare the two paths one received
from the interactive python shell and one from the output of the python file. Add the path that is missing with

```
sys.path.append("missing_path")
```

for me

```
sys.path.append("")
```

worked as I was wanted to import module from the current folder