# import from packages in other levels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this structure bellow,
I want to import data-parser/service.py classes from api/server.py how can I do it?

```
- project
    __init__.py    
    main.py
    
    - api
      __init__.py
      server.py

    - data-parser
      __init__.py
      service.py
```

Comment: Prerequisite reading before any relative import question: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: `from ..app import submodule1`.

Comment: One way is to ensure `sys.path` has the path to the project’s root directory, the import relative to that.

Comment: I'm always getting this exception: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
@9769953 this is not working as excpected

Comment: @S3DEV - im running the script now from submodule correctly

Comment: Then you're probably executing a submodule from within the package, and not from outside the package. Don't do that; that's not what a package is for.

Comment: @9769953 can you tell me more about that? best practices, and why not?

Comment: No, not best practices. Correct practice. Packages are not supposed to be run/executed, they are supposed to be imported. From *outside* their directory. That ignores inter- and intra package imports, but I'm talking from a user perspective. A user script should run *outside* the package(s) directory, then import the necessary packages.

Comment: I wrote an answer, with comments about modules, packages, relative imports and how to run things, to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102788/module-not-found-running-on-command-line/55102872#55102872 . It's still a summary, but hopefully helpful.

Comment: @9769953 I red your example and did not excactly got it, so according to my example how can I use app in api?

Comment: First edit your question to show how you are importing/using your module?

Comment: @9769953 ok I did it

Comment: Where? You state what you want, not what you do / how you run things currently.

Comment: Also, you've completely changed the names of the modules. That is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your file structure as a whole but from what I can see you have one project folder, your main script in one folder in the project folder, and your modules in a seperate folder in the project folder. If this is the case, I don't understand to why you don't just have your `main.py` file in the same directory as a folder with your modules in it (I only mention in case you can do this instead as it makes this a whole lot easier) but here is the solution if you're certain you need your file structure to be the same as it is currently:

```py
import sys
from os import path
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, path.join(Path(__file__).parent.absolute().parent.absolute(), "app"))
import submodule1
```

This, essentially, gets the path of the file, it's parent (the folder it's in), and then the parent's parent (the project folder) to add it to `sys.path` (you can use modules in the paths of this list).
I'm almost 100% certain there's a better, more efficient way of doing this, but this is what I had off the top of my head due to the uniqueness of the question. I hope it's somewhat helpful.

Comment: @S3DEV I knew something looked off! Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: any best practice of how to seperate project structure? I hvae the actuall api and the backend of it, in the future I will also have a front (that will be wrriten in Vue)?

Comment: Hacking a script or module by patching the path this way, is generally a bad idea, unless you really know what you are doing. Given the OPs mistake, I think this is a bad suggestion to use.

Comment: This is the only answer I had for this strange scenario, and it doesn't take much brain power to not completely screw up this code, it's very basic. Overall, I really think OP should just have his files together like a normal project. I asked if there was something stopping this from being a possibility but I got no response so I assume there's no reason to not have scripts in the same directory.

Comment: There is no strange scenario, afaict. There is a package called `project`, with two subpackages called `app` and `api`, each with their modules.