# Import local package from a subdirectory python

Tags: python

Edit 1: Some context - This is a data science project where `main.py` kicks off processing and analysis. It is not going to  be packaged up.

Edit 2: On why the following is not an acceptable answer: [Module not found running on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102788/module-not-found-running-on-command-line)
The solution is basically, "don't do it". This is a common data science setup. It ought to work.

Edit 3: This is the ideal solution: Create a setup.py file in the root dir:

```
# project/setup.py

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='project',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='',
    author='me',
    license='',
)
```

In your `requirements.txt` add this entry: `-e .` and run: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

---

#### Original question

My project structure is as follows:

```
project/
|-- src/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- main.py
    |-- my_module.py
```

```
# my_module
const = 1
```

```
# main.py
from src.my_module import const
```

When I run main.py as:

```
/project> python src/main.py
```

I get:

```
No module named 'src'
```

Is there a non hacky way around this problem?

Comment: Don't run a package module as a script. That's not how it's intended.

Comment: Note: `main.py/` in the structure diagram is listed as an (empty) directory. That's probably not intended.

Comment: If it's not going to be packaged up, why is there an `__init__.py` file? That's confusing. You even have `setup.py` and use it with `pip install`; I call that "packaging up".

Comment: "This is a common data science setup.": no, it's not. Scripts normally go in a separate directory, not in one that looks like a package.

Comment: Kedro and Cookiecutter are on my side: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/example_project.html and https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/

Comment: Well, I'll throw in the towel then. But I'll also stay away from those project structures, because at some point, that's going to bite you. (In fact, that already happened in this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are in the same folder, you can import it like this `from my_module import const`

Comment: Given that `src/` seems to be a package (given the `__init__.py` file), this is the wrong type of import: it mostly resembles a Python 2 relative import, and otherwise it would be an absolute import for a module inside a package, which generally is not going to work.

Comment: @9769953 Since @GlaceCelery asked for a non-hacky solution (i.e., not changing the pythonpath) this is the only one that does not produce an error while running `main.py`, appropriate or not.

Comment: It does, but it is hacky in my opinion, since the package itself (if it's ever used as a package) won't work.

Comment: I agree, but if it was to be used as a package it would have been run externally and not internally by `main.py`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use both: use `src/` as a package, and run `src/main.py` as a script.

Comment: The OP just said that this is not going to be packaged up. So this is the correct solution.

Comment: This suggestion worked. Thank you